# How to acquire precise timestamps for BLE scan events in Android?

Tags: android, timestamp, bluetooth-lowenergy, response, smartphone

I'm developing a BLE APP. It seems that the BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback occurs randomly(with different delay). So that the systemTime acquired in the callback function may not be the strict time when the adv packets arrive.
So I wanna know, is there any way for obtaining the precise timestamps(eg. in microseconds) when the BLE scan events trigger or just to promote the response speed for the scan events (which would depend on the smartphone performance)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use batch mode, you will get the advertisement packet as fast as the system can handle.

Note that on the hci level, it is not unusual for a packet to take an order of milliseconds to be transferred from the Bluetooth controller to the host over the UART lines, depending on baud rate. So don't get too high expectations. You certainly will not get microsecond precision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so is a stable milliseconds level possible? I have tested an embedded MCU that the adv packets can be accurately controlled and received. Is there any way for Android, such as coding with NDK or some way to promote the priority of the BLE report ?

Comment: Yes, the speed with which the system can handle is really a factor.
Stable, I mean that it doesn't depend on the performance of the smartphone or the tasks running.

Comment: Batch mode is beyond my capacity. We just develop APP for commercial devices. Even ROOT is not permission.

Comment: If you're not happy with the results and want precise results, you should include the timestamp in the advertisement data that the peripheral sends.

Comment: It is indeed included. But the local time in the client is used to align with the broadcaster, so an exact local timestamp is still required. 
It is really a strict requirement, I just explore the possibility. It is so kind of you for giving ideas.